# Creating a new Rest API that allow to download contents from publicly accessible website

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

Let say I am planning to create a new Rest API web service

Which allows to download contents from a given URL

End user can provide a URL and set which item they like to download, it could be images, videos, music ..etc. files on that URL page

Once an API request is made, it will return a link to ONE TIME ONLY downloadable URL, that user can use to download the requested media files ..etc.

My question is, is it legal to create an API (web service) to do that?

Comment: Without knowing the details, it's impossible to be sure.  But this sounds like it'd be copyright infringement in **most** cases.

Comment: I have seen there are a lot of API (Web services) out there that do things like take a screenshot from a given URL and let users download the image. I would assume those businesses operate in a way end users download those for private fair usage and it is ok to provide such a service?

Comment: @TW2021 You probably can't assume that. There are so many services out there that are obviously infringement, for example. The type of service you mention isn't *obviously* infringement, but in general, the less obvious the infringement, the less likely it is that any kind of action will be taken against it (e.g. DMCA takedown).

Comment: RyanM and Brandin, thanks for your feedback, I always have something interesting to build when I am learning something new, like you guys said, this will put me in trouble, I will think of something different to build, again thanks for your comments really appreciated.